# Selecting element from list to edit - Perl/CGI

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a table where user MAC addresses and other info are displayed. I am adding an edit button to each of the entries through the for loop. My problem is how can I select one of those entries to display in another subroutine? In other words, when I click the edit button for one entry how can I bring that entry info up in another subroutine where I perform the edit function?

Below is my entry listing sub.

```
print <<EOF;
<br>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <th>MAC</th>
   <th>Description</th>
   <th>UserID</th>
   <th>Edit</th>
<th>Delete</th>
   </tr>
EOF



foreach $test ( @list ) {

   print "<tr>";
   print "<td>" . scalar($test->mac()) . "</td>";
   print "<td>" . scalar($test->comment()) . "</td>\n";
   print "<td>" . scalar($test->username()) . "</td>\n";


   print "<td>" . $editButton . "</td>\n";



 print "</tr>";

  }
```

Comment: You might want to investigate [PSGI](http://plackperl.org/) as a modern alternative to CGI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting something for editing is a non-destructive operation, so you would use a link.

You need to identify the thing to edit with something unique.

Assuming the MAC address is unique (it should be for devices, but might not be for users or comments) you could use that.

```
use URI::Escape;
use HTML::Entities;

my $editButton = sprintf(
    q{<a href="edit.cgi?mac="%s">Edit</a>}, 
    encode_entities(uri_escape($test->mac()))
);
```

You can then [access the value](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI#FETCHING-THE-VALUE-OR-VALUES-OF-A-SINGLE-NAMED-PARAMETER%3a) in the script that generates the editing form.

Comment: So regardless of the amount of list items, that button would change depending on which item is clicked then carry it over to the edit sub?

Comment: Since you would construct it in the loop, and `$test->mac()` changes each time you go around the loop, it would output a different link each time. It would be passed to a script, not a sub though. (The script could do nothing except test for `mac` in the query string and pass the value to a sub though).

Comment: Is there an alternative to keep this within the same script?

Comment: `if ($q->param('mac')) { show_edit_form(); } else { show_all_macs_table(); }`

Comment: Just keep in mind that if you want to add more functions within the same script, you're better off adding some kind of action indicator so the uri looks more like href="?action=edit&mac=%s". Then, one of the first things your script does is dispatch - check the action parameter (default to list all if no action param is given), and call the appropriate subroutine: list(), edit(), update(), etc.